# One form response, add multiple table rows

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp

I have a form in which the user fills in for 'name', 'time_in','location', 'phone', 'remarks'. On occasion multiple people are reporting on the same station at the same time. Instead of duplicating the effort and submitting the same info in multiple form completions, to delimit the name field with multiple names(or in this case resource numbers ###). I have the data from the form in the controller and can accept one name or detect multiple names - delimited by *. Problem is while the code appears to save the multiple names, only the last record is found in the table after all is said and done.

[default flash messages showing records saved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReA3Y.jpg)

from the StationEntriesController the operator function performs the above.

```
public function operator() {
    // Add then list
    
    // Add information
    $stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Determine is this is mulitple entries from a single entry with '*'
        $data=$this->request->getData(); // Get form returned Data
        $namecount=0;                    // $namecount holds number of names held in single name record
        if (isset($data['name'])) {      // It is posted data and name is filled in
            $name=$data['name'];         // Pull 'name' out of array
            if(strpos($name, '*')){      // Check 'name' for * indicating multiple names need handling
                unset($newdata);
                do{
                    $firstPos=strpos($name, '*');                   // Find first * position in 'name'
                    $nameToDelimeter=substr($name, 0,$firstPos);    // create string from beginning to * substring of 'name'
                    $nameToDelimeter=chop($nameToDelimeter," ");             // Remove any ' ' from the string
                    if(strlen($nameToDelimeter)==3){                // len will always be 3 if user applied correctly. (error hanlding to follow)
                        // $newdata is now array of form posted data with 1 of n 'name's and all other data remains the same.
                        $newdata[]=['location'=>$data['location'],'name'=>$nameToDelimeter, 'time_in'=>$data['time_in'],'phone'=>$data['phone'],'remarks'=>$data['remarks']];
                        $namecount++;       // increment name count
                    }
                    $name=substr($name, $firstPos+1);           // trim $name from beginning to * and leave the rest
                }while(strpos($name, '*'));
                // all delimters are out of $name now, so should be just one name left, let's add it to array copying other data
                $name=chop($name," ");
                $newdata[]=['location'=>$data['location'],'name'=>$name, 'time_in'=>$data['time_in'],'phone'=>$data['phone'],'remarks'=>$data['remarks']];
                $namecount++;
                $data=$newdata;
                // End of form data manipulation
            }
        } 
        if($namecount){
            // cycle through $data array and update database with the mutliple records
            for($datacount=0;$datacount<$namecount;$datacount++){
                $stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->patchEntity($stationEntry, $data[$datacount]); //add one row at a time 
                    if ($this->StationEntries->save($stationEntry)) {
                        $this->Flash->default(__($data[$datacount]['name'].' has been logged on station.' ));
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->error(__('The station entry could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }
            }
            $this->redirect(['action' => 'operator']);
        } else {
            $stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->patchEntity($stationEntry, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->StationEntries->save($stationEntry)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The station entry has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'operator']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The station entry could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->StationEntries->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('stationEntry', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['stationEntry']);
```

Entering into form the data:

```
'location' = "AnyWhere"
'name'     = "309*214*217"
'time_in'  = *Current* datetime
'phone'    = ""
'remarks'  = "Applicable Notes"
```

returns the following data:

```
[
    'location' => 'AnyWhere',
    'name' => '309*214*217',
    'time_in' => [
        'year' => '2017',
        'month' => '08',
        'day' => '09',
        'hour' => '19',
        'minute' => '28'
    ],
    'phone' => '',
    'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
]
```

The manipulated form data in $data[] now shows:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '309',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '214',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '217',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ]
]
```

This is supposed to add to database one record at a time via

```
$stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->patchEntity($stationEntry, $data[$datacount]);
$this->StationEntries->save($stationEntry)
```

Only the '217' record is saving- every field is correct for it, just one instead of three entries. Entries for '309', and '214' are not in table. I believe this method is unstable as once, I can't replicate, it did create three entries but all with name of 217.

I am trying to stay within the confines of cakephp and it's data security methods. This is my "jump in the deep end" way of learning cakephp so trying to avoid the manual sql INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO `station_entries`(`location`, `name`, `time_in`, `time_out`, `phone`, `remarks`) 
VALUES 
('Anywhere', '309', '3017-08-09 19:28','','Applicable Notes'), 
('Anywhere', '214', '3017-08-09 19:28','','Applicable Notes'), 
('Anywhere', '217', '3017-08-09 19:28','','Applicable Notes');
```

Any help and/or feed back is appreciated. Is there a way to add, as this case, 3 records via a cakephp statement that I am just unfamiliar with, and what is it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `explode('*',  $name)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$data =[
    (int) 0 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '309',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '214',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'location' => 'AnyWhere',
        'name' => '217',
        'time_in' => [
            'year' => '2017',
            'month' => '08',
            'day' => '09',
            'hour' => '19',
            'minute' => '28'
        ],
        'phone' => '',
        'remarks' => 'Applicable Notes'
    ]
];


foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
$stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->newEntity();
$stationEntry = $this->StationEntries->patchEntity($stationEntry, $d);
$this->StationEntries->save($stationEntry);
}
```

Comment: It's so simple looking at it now!  Yes... That has it working. Very elegant. Thank you Ajay!

Comment: thanks if you don't mind you can also give a up voting for this ans